# R: using Matplot to plot a table and a curve on same graph and same scale

Tags: r

I have a table:
    y

```
           1            2            3            4            5            6 
0.2414412019 0.5032905670 0.1956391677 0.0422788008 0.0081100844 0.0015289503 
           7            8            9           15           20           24 
0.0003323805 0.0001329522 0.0001994283 0.0000664761 0.0000664761 0.0000664761 
          26           27           28           29           30           38 
0.0009971415 0.0007312371 0.0023266636 0.0010636176 0.0004653327 0.0001329522 
          39           40           41           42 
0.0001994283 0.0005318088 0.0003323805 0.0000664761 

is.table(y)
[1] TRUE
```

Originally, if I want to create a plot, I could simply do plot(y), which look likes this
[image]

However, now I would like to add another curve to this plot, i.e. `dpois(1:42, lambda = 10)`. And I would like to preserve the scale by using matplot. But since y is a table not a vector, I have no idea how to use matplot to solve the problem. *I do not want to use par(new = T) blablabla, since it doesnt always preserve the scale and I am working with many tables with different length*

**Note:** my goal is to reproduce the plot above (the vertical lines must be preserved, I do not want histogram or bars. In other words, I wish the table structure of `y` can be preserved) with an additional curve on the same graph. Can I use matplot or other function to achieve this in R?

Data structure below

```
dput(y)
structure(c(0.241441201887921, 0.503290567041149, 0.195639167719205, 
0.0422788007711228, 0.00811008442464934, 0.00152895034235192, 
0.00033238050920694, 0.000132952203682776, 0.000199428305524164, 
6.6476101841388e-05, 6.6476101841388e-05, 6.6476101841388e-05, 
0.00099714152762082, 0.000731237120255268, 0.00232666356444858, 
0.00106361762946221, 0.000465332712889716, 0.000132952203682776, 
0.000199428305524164, 0.000531808814731104, 0.00033238050920694, 
6.6476101841388e-05), class = "table", .Dim = 22L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "15", "20", 
    "24", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
    "42")), .Names = ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

If so, all you need to do is add `lines(dpois(1:42, lambda = 10))`. That is:

```
y = dput(structure(c(0.241441201887921, 0.503290567041149, 0.195639167719205, 
            0.0422788007711228, 0.00811008442464934, 0.00152895034235192, 
            0.00033238050920694, 0.000132952203682776, 0.000199428305524164, 
            6.6476101841388e-05, 6.6476101841388e-05, 6.6476101841388e-05, 
            0.00099714152762082, 0.000731237120255268, 0.00232666356444858, 
            0.00106361762946221, 0.000465332712889716, 0.000132952203682776, 
            0.000199428305524164, 0.000531808814731104, 0.00033238050920694, 
            6.6476101841388e-05), class = "table", .Dim = 22L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
              c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "15", "20", 
                "24", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
                "42")), .Names = "")))

windows()
  plot(y)
  lines(dpois(1:42, lambda=10))
```

See [?lines](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/lines.html) for more information.